# UFT and HP ALM connectivty

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm

I have installed HP UFT v12.01 and when trying to connect via HP UFT to HP ALM Quality Center v11.0 and I get the following error:

Failed to update components from server.
Failed Hosting the Spider ActiveX

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps below

- Launch IE as admin and navigate to ALM Tools
- From the ALM Tools page, select "HP ALM Connectivity" and run. 
  You should receive an    "Installation Successful" message.
- From the ALM Tools page, select "HP ALM Client Registration"
  and "Register HP ALM."
- Log into your ALM Client to make sure that works.
- Run UFT as administrator (this just needs to be done the first time
  when connecting to ALM).
- Try connecting to ALM and see if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3):

If logging into ALM first, and then connecting to ALM through UFT does not work (as suggested by Vvvaib above), then try this:
- Open UFT as an administrator (right-click on icon, select "Run as Administrator") and then try logging into ALM.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. Solution that worked for me is- close UFT.
Login to ALM using your valid credentials from IE. Now launch UFT. Probably this error would not appear any more. If it still does then from UFT go to your ALM credentials settings remove them and restart UFT and fill the credentials again and connect. Problem should get solved. I don't know the exact reason behind this error.

Answer (score 0):

Disable UAC and antivirus if any. Login as administrator and then invoke UFT and try to connect ALM. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete ALM client. You can do this by deleting files from below folders:

- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp
- C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\HP
- C:\Users\All Users\HP
- C:\ProgramData\HP

After that run UFT with admin rights. When you successfully connect to ALM rerun UFT without admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Server URL which you are using in the ALM Connection Dialog box.

use [Server Url](https://alm12-ota.es.corpintra.net/qcbin).

and follow the:

1. Launch IE as admin and navigate to ALM Tools
2. From the ALM Tools page, select "HP ALM Connectivity" and run. You should receive an "Installation Successful" message.
3. From the ALM Tools page, select "HP ALM Client Registration" and "Register HP ALM."
4. Log into your ALM Client to make sure that works.
5. Run UFT as administrator (this just needs to be done the first time when connecting to ALM).
6. Try connecting to ALM.